# VBA- Iterating through string values in an array and identifying if they are equal to a specific text

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, userform

I have a data set in excel with a lot of columns. I'm using a UserForm Entry to populate those columns. But I also want to be able to write an existing ID in the userform and autopopulate the useform with its corresponding data being pulled from the spreadsheet. The order of the columns might change, so I don't want to use the offset function to do this.

What I'm trying to do in the my code is to make an array with all the column names (it's corresponding text boxes in the entry form are named the same).

First, I'm finding the row for the ID. Then I want to iterate through the different columns and find the values under them that correspond to the ID to populate my entry form.

The problem is that I want to use "array(i)" as the name of a text box in my userform but it doesn't read it. For example:

If I directly write MRN = Cells(CSN_R, Changing_C), it does populate the entry form with the right data, as it selects the id row and column number under "MRN" or "Myarray(0)". But if I use myarray(0) =Cells(CSN_R, Changing_C) it doesn't.... I don't know what to do to make it work.

```
    Dim CSN_Find As Range
    Dim CSN_Existing As Range
    Dim CSN_New As Range

    Dim CSN_R As Integer
    Dim Changing_C As Integer

    ' Look for the CSN value

    Worksheets("Input Data").Activate
    Worksheets("Input Data").Rows(1).Find(What:="CSN", LookIn:=xlValues).EntireColumn.Select

    Set CSN_Find = Selection.Find(What:=CSN.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    ' If it's found, then populate form

    If (Not CSN_Find Is Nothing) Then

        CSN_Find.Activate
        CSN_R = ActiveCell.Row


        Dim myarray As Variant
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim lastColumn As Integer


        myarray = Array("MRN", "ArrivalDate",...(I have a lot))

        lastColumn = Worksheets("Input Data").Cells(1, columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        i = 0

        Do Until i = lastColumn + 1

        Changing_C = Worksheets("Input Data").Rows(1).Find(What:=myarray(i), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Column

        myarray(i) = Cells(CSN_R, Changing_C) **** not working

        i = i + 1
        Loop

    ' Else, do nothing:

    Else: If CSN_Find Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I just added this and it works but it's going to require a bunch of if statements...
        
            
            If myarray(i) = "MRN" Then
            MRN = Cells(CSN_R, Changing_C)
            End If
            
            If myarray(i) = "ArrivalDate" Then
            ArrivalDate = Cells(CSN_R, Changing_C)
            End If

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use this `myarray(i) = Cells(CSN_R, Changing_C) **** not working` you're just overwriting your array values

It looks like what you're trying to do is assign the text to the userform control textbox. You should be able to refer to the textbox via the userform name - what is it called?

Say it's the default "UserForm1" you can use:

```
UserForm1.Controls(myarray(i)).Text = Cells(CSN_R, Changing_C)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed!!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
Me.Controls(myarray(i)) = Cells(CSN_R, Changing_C)
```